# Bypass a third party API that blocks requests from Google App Engine

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-403

I need to pull data from a third party API. Their server blocks request made from Google App Engine(all request made from GAE get a nice header stating it came from App-Engine :|). Always get Http 403 Forbidden.

Is there a way to configure App Engine to use some kind of a proxy to avoid being denied from making request to the API?

I have tested the webservice locally and it worked great. The App Engine runs in a different country (europe-west).

I am using HttpURLConnection to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that App Engine has a set of headers that cannot be modified, so in case one of these is part of the API’s criteria for blocking your requests, you will have no luck there.

There are a few of them that can be modified, however, so I recommend you test to see if that is indeed the case, as it will same you a lot of trouble. You can find more information about the App Engine’s “must have” outbound headers in the [Outbound Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/outbound-requests#request_headers) documentation.

Since you mentioned the location of your App Engine app (europe-west), I am also inclined to think that this could be the cause of the issue. I suggest testing to see if an app deployed in a **different region** receives the same response.

Being the issue with App Engine’s headers or with the location, you could solve it by setting up a “proxy server”, which can be hosted on a [Google Compute Engine Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance), and configure the server to **remove these headers**.

The correct configuration will depend on which server you choose, Squid, as an example, offers a [request_header_access](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/) for that. You can then use the **Proxy API** to redirect only the API calls to the proxy server. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connect-via-proxy-server#1-using-an-http-proxy) you can find a nice explanation about how to use the Proxy API.

It is also important to notice that **removing header goes against the** [Guidelines for Web Content Transformation Proxies 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/ct-guidelines/#sec-altering-header-values), so it would be nice to confirm why the target API has this limitation with calls coming from App Engine, before deciding how to proceed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: comparing your solution with other alternatives, I have decided to work with AWS instead. Solving this issue was not straight forward and involved using third party proxies.